# To make thank you page works

Tags: php

I have wrote this code to make a thank you page.
It should work that one time only it show thank you to avoid it is repeated with a simple refresh or redirect from another foreign page but only from index where I set the variable to 'true'.
First, I set the variable on the index.php in this way:

```
$_SESSION['fromMain'] = "true";
```

Then in the thankyou.php I wrote this:

```
if($_SESSION['fromMain'] == "true"){
    
    $_SESSION['fromMain'] = "false";
    echo "TRUE, thank you!";
    
}  else {

    echo "FALSE";
    
}
```

It always show 'TRUE'.
I did something wrong?

Comment: how did you set `$_SESSION['fromMain']`? if you set it at the beginning of your code and never change, it will always `true`

Comment: I set fromMain to true in the index.php just to test it. Then I go to thankyou.php and it show true. But when it show true the variable is already set to false then but if I refresh it still show true.

Comment: Did you properly start the session again in thankyou.php?

Comment: @CBroe maybe not how to do that?

Comment: I am asking whether you have called `session_start();` properly, at the beginning of every script involved?

Comment: @CBroe it works now with `session_start();` thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You declared `$_SESSION['fromMain'] = "true";`
then  you are testing  if its true or not which it will always be

i think the problem is here

```
if($_SESSION['fromMain'] == "true"){

$_SESSION['fromMain'] = "false";
echo "TRUE, thank you!";
```

}

Comment: `$_SESSION['fromMain'] = "true";` is set on another page (index.php).